# About Datastax "Monitoring a Cassandra cluster" Documentation

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, nodetool

In this [1] document, when it describes cfstats output it says, **Read count** is the `Number of pending read requests`. Is that correct? I was thinking that is all read requests received since last server restart.

can someone please clarify this?

[1] http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/cassandra/operations/ops_monitoring_c.html

Thanks,
Bhathiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, the docs are wrong. cfstats read count is the number of local read requests for the table since start up.